# Maven axis2-wsdl2code Inner class incompatible types

Tags: java, maven, apache-axis

Trying to upgrade from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8 , I'm using maven plugin to generate the stub file from wsdl

Earlier , I was using Java 1.7 to generate them, stub files are fine.

Now Since i upgraded to Java 1.8 , i could see this stub has renamed inner class which results in compilation failure.

*Error: incompatible types: AMS_type0[] cannot be converted to AMS_type2[]*

We could change the implementation classes, but wanted to understand why this behavior and to minimize testing effort. Below is my maven command

[image]

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade the axis2-wsdl2code plugin version to the most recent one....

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Even with latest version its the same. Not sure why though. I have changed the impl.